# Is there a way to serialize and deserialize ALL dates to UTC milliseconds?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javers

I am trying to standardize dates across our application to send UTC milliseconds in the requests and responses.

The application is using Spring Boot for a REST backend. I have added `BasicStringTypeAdapters` for `java.util.Date`, `java.time.LocalDateTime`, and `java.time.Instant` as below, but none are being applied.

If I add a dummy one for `java.lang.String`, it works, so I know these are registered in the appropriate place.

However, I believe that the code [here](https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/22de513ba99a892d249216ef53ab27edcddabfd4/javers-core/src/main/java/org/javers/core/json/JsonConverterBuilder.java#L148-L163) is unconditionally overwriting these adapters. Specifically `registerJsonTypeAdapters(Java8TypeAdapters.adapters());` overwrites `java.time.LocalDateTime` and `java.time.Instant` and (I believe) `gsonBuilder.serializeNulls().setDateFormat(ISO_DATE_TIME_FORMAT);` overwrites `java.util.Date`.

If I am incorrect, can someone please point me in the right direction on how to serialize all dates as UTC millis?

If I am correct, can I still get some advice on how to proceed?

```java
return TransactionalJaversBuilder
        .javers()
        .withTxManager(transactionManager)
        .withObjectAccessHook(new HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook())
        .registerJaversRepository(sqlRepository)
        .registerValueTypeAdapter(
            new BasicStringTypeAdapter<Date>() {
              @Override
              public Class getValueType() {
                return Date.class;
              }

              @Override
              public String serialize(Date value) {
                return String.valueOf(value.getTime());
              }

              @Override
              public Date deserialize(String in) {
                return new Date(Long.valueOf(in));
              }
            }
        )
        .registerValueTypeAdapter(
            new BasicStringTypeAdapter<LocalDateTime>() {
              @Override
              public Class getValueType() {
                return LocalDateTime.class;
              }

              @Override
              public String serialize(LocalDateTime value) {
                return String.valueOf(value.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli());
              }

              @Override
              public LocalDateTime deserialize(String in) {
                return Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.valueOf(in)).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
              }
            }
        )
        .registerValueTypeAdapter(
            new BasicStringTypeAdapter<Instant>() {
              @Override
              public Class getValueType() {
                return Instant.class;
              }

              @Override
              public String serialize(Instant value) {
                return String.valueOf(value.toEpochMilli());
              }

              @Override
              public Instant deserialize(String in) {
                return Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.valueOf(in));
              }
            }
        )
        .build();
```

Comment: Could you set some breakpoints or log statements to be sure it is reaching your code?

Comment: I have. It calls `getValueType` for all of the above and, if I register an adapter of a different type (i.e. `String`), it works exactly as expected. The code is being called, I just believe the registrations are being overridden

Comment: hi @SeaMauFive, could you write a failing test case for this issue and push it here https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-core/src/test/groovy/org/javers/core/cases ?

Comment: @BartekWalacik PR here https://github.com/javers/javers/pull/938. Let me know if I missed anything. Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: just for the records, @SeaMauFive has contributed a fix for this issue, it's released in Javers 5.8.10